# Open my App with URL - Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app.... and I want to open my app when someone types the url in browser.. I'm able to get the "Complete Action Using.." and My app also shows there ONLY when I click the bookmark to the web link.. However if I type the URL in browser it simply loads up the website.. but I want to redirect it to my app.

Here is my code in Manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="SOME_URL.SOMETHING"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

*SOME_URL.SOMETHING  is the name of website to load.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Which browser? Chrome doesn't respect intent filters.

Comment: The Stock Android Browser.

Comment: @iamPranavSethi: you can get some help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176983/add-my-app-to-the-list-of-complete-action-using-for-attachments-in-gmail